# Is the question mark required?

Tags: swift, option-type

I was reviewing the code of an ex-collegue, when I found this one:

```
if task != nil {
            // why is "?" here?
            task?.cancel()
            task = nil
        }
```

`task` is declared as an optional.

I'm supposing at that point task can't be **nil** anymore. So why the developer puts a question mark? Couldn't I insert an exclamation mark, instead?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can put ! mark like task!.cancel().

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani so, correct me if I'm wrong: there's apparently no reason why he left the question mark

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani No, do not use `task!.cancel()`. That can still cause a crash if `task` gets changed on another thread. Use optional binding instead of `if task != nil` followed by `task!.something`.

Comment: @3000 all comment will be based on an assumption so if you have another thread so not to use `!` while it is best practice to use `?` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to compiler hint the `?` may be put by the compiler, not your colleague.

Instead, you could use an `if let` statement as follows:

```
if let task2 = task {
    task2.cancel()
    task = nil
}
```

The `task` is calling `cancel()` so that may be task is `nil`, here we notify to the compiler by `?` for the task, If the compiler will get `nil` it goes silently without crashing.

Comment: @3000 no need to check if it is nil when calling `task?.cancel()`. This will never crash your app. If task it is nil it will silently fail

Comment: Yes, this will not crash if you are using '?' in task?.cancel()

Comment: @LeoDabus there are two lines of code: he checks it even to nil the value of task if task exists and it is not nil

Comment: @3000 Again the nil checking in this case is redundant. Better to remove the nil checking instead of force unwrapping it inside the conditional.

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right, I was focusing too much on the presence of the ?  :-)

Comment: Since we don't know the context of the OP:s code, this answer gives some dangerous advice: if the type of `task` is a value type, and if `cancel()` is a `mutating` method, then upon calling `cancel()` on the `task2` instance, this will be invoked to _a copy_ of the original `task` (`task2` will be, due to COW, a copy of `task` upon mutation), whereas the `cancel()` method will not have been invoked on the original `task` instance.

Comment: @dfri Thanks for pointing this out but cancel is not mutating and task is a reference type

Comment: @3000 the `task` is calling `cancel()` so that may be task is `nil`, here we notify to the compiler by `?` for the `task`  if the compiler will get `nil` it goes silently without crashing.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani I know how anything works (I knew it even before posting), my question was about the need of the "?" but Leo Dabus comment let me focus on the entire code, not only "?"

Answer (score 1):

> *Thanks for pointing this out but cancel is not mutating and `task` is a reference type*

You've mentioned that `task` is a reference type, so the optional binding methods show in the other answers will be ok even due to the copying/binding that occurs when optionally binding and mutating a value. Note, however, that you needn't necessarily resort to optional binding to cover the logic in the snippet you've shown, but can instead simply combine the optional chaining and the `nil` check within a single conditional (and only setting the property to `nil` within the body of the conditional).

```
// if task is non-nil, cancel it and set it to 'nil'
// if task is already nil, do nothing
if task?.cancel() != nil { task = nil }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should unwrap the value by doing: `if let task = task` if you want to avoid the question mark.

Comment: I've nothing against the question marks   :-)   I was just curious about the "mental process" that led my collegue to leave it where it was after testing task!=nil

Comment: Even if you tested `task!=nil`, you can set task to nil inside like shown in the code. Hence why task is still an optional, so you **have** to put the question mark. If you want to unwrap task with `if let`, then you won't need to put the question mark, but you also won't be able to set it to nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can unwrap the optional using `if let` or `guard`, then you don't need `?` or `!`

Answer (score 0):

You can unwrap optional using Guard statements too

```
    //This will not unwrap the optional. It will remain optional
    if task != nil {   
       task?.cancel() //That is why the compiler added the question mark automatically 
    }



   // This will unwrap the optional variable
    guard let task2 = task else {
       return
    }

    // task will be optional but task2 will not

    task?.cancel()
    task? = nil

    task2.cancel()
    task2 = nil
```